# Google Cloud: New shared BigQuery datasets and GCP projects is not visible for my user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I am not seeing new projects or BigQuery datasets that have been shared with me.

My colleague have tried to share a new BigQury dataset with me but it is not visible for me. We have tried to share the same dataset with another user the exact same way without any issue.

We have a similar issue with my user when we try to share any new GCP projects with my user, which have not been an issue in the past.

**Information about the setup and my user:**

I am using a google account which is part of another organization than the GCP organization we are having this issue with. My user has an editor role to project 1 of the organization. 
The BigQuery dataset my colleague (who is the admin role for the GCP organization) is in project 2. 
The other user my colleague successfully shared the dataset with was his private google account. 
We tried adding my user to project 2 with the editor role, but it did not show up in my project overview as it normally would.

How do we fix this and what can cause this issue?

Comment: Which actions are you taking to share the dataset?

Comment: I have clicked on Share dataset in the interface, entered the email address, selected the BigQuery data editor role and clicked share

Comment: Can you find the mentioned dataset if you search for it on the search bar in the right? (Search for your tables and datasets)

Comment: No, it is not visible when I search for it

Comment: Can you try following this steps?  1) Go to the BQ console  2) Click on + Add Data just above the search bar  3) Click on Pin a Project   4) Enter the project ID and click on PIN

Comment: Please let me know if it works

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. I followed your steps and my colleague when reshared the dataset with me

Comment: Ill add it as an answer so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose you have **project1** and **project2** and you've never shared any dataset from project1 with project2.
When you first share a dataset from project1 with project2, the dataset will not be shown automatically. 
For that, you need to follow this steps:

1. Go to the BQ console
2. Click on + Add Data just above the search bar
3. Click on Pin a Project
4. Enter the project ID and click on PIN

After that, every dataset inside project1 that you share with project2 will be automatically shown.